# Polymer is not defined

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, lit-element, lit-html

I am trying to call a function on the click of paper-button in my polymer application.
But polymer throws error there:

[image]

I searched for the same error I found that we should import polymer.html.
I have also imported polymer.html in my index file, but still, it's failing:

[image]

I am not getting what I did wrong.

Comment: try add <link> to index.html. You should move to LitElement because polymer 2 is deprecated like a polymer 3

Comment: this screenshot is fromm index.html only. I have added the link in index.html only

Answer (score 1):

You're not loading the polyfills correctly. They are not HTML files to be loaded with HTML imports, you need to load them with a `<script>` tag:

```html
<script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
```

Note: HTML Imports have been removed from Chrome, so every browser requires the polyfill now. I'd switch to Polymer 3.x as soon as you can. From there you can upgrade to LitElement incrementally.